# Why we use gtmpl file in juzu framework development?

Tags: java, jsp, groovy, juzu

Can someone explain to me what is the usefulness of using gtmpl files when developing for the juzu framework, instead of jsp files or others?

Comment: no I mean gtmpl file using into juzu framework for presentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gtmpl is a simple template engine inherited from Groovy Templates that works pretty well.

In addition Juzu also supports Mustache templating (http://juzuweb.org/reference/index.html#_the_mustache_template_engine) as logic-less template engine.

It is technically possible to integrate other template engines. However Juzu does not support (yet) JSP because they would not work with the Juzu Vert.x bridge.

Answer (score 2):

I guess because `gtmpl` files contain Groovy code, allowing things like (from the documentation)

```
<% ["red","green","blue"].each { color -> out.print( "<li>The sky is ${color}</li>" ) } %>
```

Rather than the for loop you'd need to write in a jsp

Comment: yes thank you, this is an example

but I do not think it is invented for this stuff .. Necessarily that there is something else that does not do JSP or other languages

otherwise why this language is invented

Comment: Groovy wasn't invented for the juzu framework. Groovy is a language that the default juzu templates use to simplify development for the user. Other frameworks leverage groovy as well, ie Grails in its gsp files and play v1

Comment: thank you again tim_yates ..that's it "to simplify development". I will look for more examples ;)